# I'm trying to open firebase website in my app but it requests for external browser

Tags: android, firebase, webview, firebase-console

I am trying to open the **firebase** website inside my app using **webview**. But the app requests for external browser while opening that activity.

```
public class FirebaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView firebase;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebase);
        firebase = findViewById(R.id.firebase);
        this.firebase.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        this.firebase.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        firebase.loadUrl("https://console.firebase.google.com/");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting WebViewClient should resolve the issue.

```
public class FirebaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView firebase;
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              view.loadUrl(url);
              return true;
          }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebase);
        firebase = findViewById(R.id.firebase);
        firebase.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        firebase.loadUrl("https://console.firebase.google.com/");
        firebase.requestFocus();
    }
}
```